# How should I punctuate this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

During the interview, I asked Ms. Smith what geared her towards teaching students with special needs.

Comment: Hi, Jane—and thanks for your interest in English Language & Usage. I notice that someone has already offered an answer to your question, but the type of question you've asked (which amounts to a request for proofreading help) is off-topic for this site and will probably be closed. If you can reframe your question as a more general question about punctuation, it might be of more interest to our community; but as asked, it has almost no long-term value at this site.

Comment: steered her, not geared her.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you keep the wording--(I would definitely change "what geared her towards teaching" to "why she wanted to teach")--it's punctuated correctly.

The question mark mentioned in the previous answer is incorrect. The independent clause is "I asked..." which is not a question but a comment. If you were quoting the question you asked Mrs. Smith, then the question mark would appear, but it would be inside the ending quote mark.

```
   During the interview, I said to Mrs. Smith, "What geared
   you towards teaching students with special needs?"
```

In this case, the thing you're quoting is a question. When you're telling your reader that you asked someone a question, you're not actually asking the question. You're making a statement about what you said.